# node js interact with shell application

Tags: shell, node.js, stdin, read-eval-print-loop

There are plenty of node js examples on online about how to spawn a child process and then catch the result as a string for your own processing.

But...

I want to 'interact' with a child process. For example, how would I write a node js application than starts by calling '`python`' and then types a statement '`1+1`', lets me catch the result '`2`', before proceeding to type another arbitrary statement '`4+4`'?

(And by 'type' I'm assuming it will require streaming data to the stdin that the process uses).

Comment: This video also shows what I'm trying to do (at 3:52) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16nFMucvwYQ

Comment: Related: [javascript - Spawning a child process with tty in node.js - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866207/spawning-a-child-process-with-tty-in-node-js)

Answer (score 9):

```
var child = require('child_process');
var ps = child.spawn('python', ['-i']);
ps.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
ps.stdin.write('1+1');
ps.stdin.end();
```

works a treat!