# How to emulate programmatically CLI prompts input with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, child-process

I'm trying to make a NodeJS script who automatises the execution of [Gatsby CLI](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/).
Basically when we launch `gatsby new` it looks like that :

[image: The Gatsby CLI]

So, in my NodeJS script I execute this command with the `child_process` like that :

```js
exec('gatsby new', (_error, _stdout) => {
  if (_error) {
   console.error(`exec error: ${_error}`);
  }
  console.log(`${_stdout}`);
});
```

The problem is that I'm unable to answer to the [Gatsby CLI](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/) question especially with the arrow-keys questions.

Comment: By "respond" you mean that you want to send keyboard input to the spawned application?

Comment: [javascript - Spawning a child process with tty in node.js - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866207/spawning-a-child-process-with-tty-in-node-js) ?

Comment: Yes when the Gatsby CLI ask questions like "What is your project called?", I would like to  answer "test" for example. The further difficulty is to emulate arrow-keys for some questions

Comment: I would think that Gatsby has an API for this. Don't spawn a subprocess and communicate with it by text - just call the right function with your options directly. You might have to do some digging around the CLI source code to find it, but surely it's there.

Comment: If the key sequence is fixed, the question I link above should work.