# interacting with gdb works unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, gdb, pipe

I'm just toying around trying to control gdb, the *toy* is a front for gdb.

Code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905343/368070): works perfect for me with python3 on my fedora system. But for some reason doesn't work with gdb.

This works :

```
var child = require('child_process');
var ps = child.spawn('python', ['-i']);
ps.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
ps.stdin.write('1+1');
ps.stdin.end();
```

This does not work:

```
var child = require('child_process');
var ps = child.spawn("gdb", ['gdb-test', '-q']);
ps.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
ps.stdin.write('start');
```

Issues: **(1)** it prints this to stdout:

> Reading symbols from gdb-test...Reading symbols from gdb-test...done.

So for some reason it's as if the command was run twice.  **(2)** most importantly the *start* command isn't fed into gdb and it doesn't do it's usual thing of putting a breakpoint inside main.

Eg: If I run manually inside bash, *start* would result in : *"Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at gdb-test.c:5"*

**gdb-test** is this code compiled :

```
//gdb-test.c:
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    i++;
    printf("%d\n"); 
}
```

I know [gdb has](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#Mode-Options) a *-tty* option, I'm not so sure how setting up a tty is even supposed to work, any clues here will also be welcomed, or clues on setting up a tty and interacting with gdb's machine interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the start command isn't fed into gdb and it doesn't
>   do it's usual thing of putting a breakpoint inside main

When you type `start` command manually in gdb prompt you are pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to actually execute it. You should do the same in js script. Add `\n` at the end of `start` command:

```
ps.stdin.write('start\n');
```

As for the **(1)** issue I was unable to reproduce it on Fedora.

Comment: oh jeez. That's embarrassing. Guess I was all over the place in my head doing all kinds of different things.  Also issue **1** was happening also because code on my machine was piping the process output to stdout twice. :/ I need to relax somewhere now :) thanks!